# Can regression and classifiers both be checked for accuracy?

Tags: regression, classification

As much as I know regression is used for forecasting  and we use R square to know how the model better fits, it.

Unlike classifiers where we separate two sets and then use it for predicting the new values.

So can measures used for calculating accuracy in classifiers be also used for linear regression like models?

Comment: Yes we estimate the misclassification error rates which we want to be low.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$R^2  = 1-\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \hat{y_i})^2}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_i - \bar{y})^2}$ tells us about the fit within the sample used for estimation.

If we have strong reasons to believe that the model we are estimating should hold out of sample, then it should also give us an idea about the model's value as a forecaster. However, this is typically not a very good assumption.

Cross Validation can be done to get a better sense of how the model does out of sample and just like with clustering techniques a number of cost functions can be used as out test statistic. Very briefly, K-fold Cross Validation involves splitting the data into k non-overlapping sections. $K-1$ of those folds are used to estimate the model, and the withheld data is used to calculate the cost function. This process is repeated K times. 5 and 10 are typical values for k. It is becoming increasingly suggested that K-fold Cross Validation be repeated a number of times in it's use for parameter selection and model fit, since at relatively small numbers it is subject to high variation and at high values of K it is subject to bias.

Out of sample $R^2$, root-mean-squared error (RMSE), BIC,AIC, and binomial deviance are all examples of such cost functions. These of course have different advantages and drawbacks depending on the application and the type of regression model being used.